# Error:java.lang.IllegalAccessException: no such method: io.appium.java_client

Tags: android

I need to setup Appium on Android studio. I am using mac machine.
My android version is 3.0 and once I add java-client jar which is downloaded from appium.io I am getting following error. Please help me to resolve this:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/0.jar --output /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/1.jar --input /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/5.jar --output /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/6.jar --input /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/6.jar --output /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/7.jar --input /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/8.jar --output /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/9.jar --input /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/28.jar --output /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/29.jar --input /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/29.jar --output /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/30.jar --input /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/10.jar --output /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/11.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/1.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/2.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/3.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/4.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/5.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/6.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/7.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/8.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/9.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/10.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/11.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/12.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/13.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/14.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/15.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/16.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/17.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/18.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/19.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/20.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/21.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/22.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/23.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/24.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/25.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/26.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/27.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/28.jar --classpath_entry /Users/macair16/AndroidStudioProjects/Appium5/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/29.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Users/macair16/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Users/macair16/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-26/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar --min_sdk_version 26 --nodesugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes}

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s

21 actionable tasks: 20 executed, 1 up-to-date

Comment: Do you get any solution for this issue? Please add your comment below!

Comment: Yes I downloaded  Appium from node.js then every thing worked fine for me. I guess this error is due to mismatch of versions of jars and appium

Comment: hmm!! I have already installed node.js but did not get succeed on that Can you please specify the which jar and its version you have used currently? It is also fine if you specify the appium version that you have used!!

Comment: Appium v1.7.2 and java client 5.0.4 and selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar these are the versions which are working fine for me. Hope it helps you..